# Printing line number in MatLab (including the line number of upper-level function)?

Tags: matlab

Suppose main.m calls func1.m, and func1.m calls func2.m in three parts of func1.m

Suppose I am printing some variables in func2.m because there was some error.

So suppose I printed

```
var2 = 3
var2 = 5
var2 = -1
```

I am just talking about an example. But if the program is very complex, then since func1.m is calling func2.m at three points, I can get confused as to which part of func1.m is generating var2=3 at func2.m

So if I can print the "line number" of current line (including the line number of upper-level function), then it will be very useful for debugging.

Is there such thing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`dbstack`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstack.html) to figure out what line of the calling function called this. You could look for `func1` specifically in the call stack.

```
stack = dbstack();
[~, ind] = ismember({stack.name}, 'func1');
disp(stack(ind).line)
```

That being said, it is *far* better to set a conditional break point and then use `dbup` and `dbdown` or the MATLAB workspace browser to navigate to parent and child workspaces to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you. But I am curious why some experts say using dbup and dbdown is good for debugging. I cannot trace back variables that have been already overwritten. Especially inside for, while loop, variables get wiped out quickly. When I want to see how they are getting changed over looping iterations, dbup and dbdown aren't very helpful, are they?

Comment: @user42459 Typically well written code is broken up into modular pieces with their own variable scope. Because of that, there are often very few variable names within a function and they won't be overwritten.

Comment: @user42459 Also you would put a breakpoint *before* your loop and manually iterate through your loop or set a conditional break point that is triggered with a specific loop iteration.